# Division de una cadena en Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tengo esta cadena

```
'https://img-c.udemycdn.com/course/240x135/1265942_7e2f_19.jpg 1x, https://img-c.udemycdn.com/course/480x270/1265942_7e2f_19.jpg 2x'
```

y me gustaria dividirla en 2 para que las dos imagenes queden separadas, cual es la mejor manera de hacerlo? sin usar regex?

probe con slice, split, splice pero no funcionan

Answer (score 3):

tienes que usar split para dividir la cadena cada vez que encuentre una coma

```
const cadena = 'https://img-c.udemycdn.com/course/240x135/1265942_7e2f_19.jpg 1x, https://img-c.udemycdn.com/course/480x270/1265942_7e2f_19.jpg 2x'

const urls = cadena.split(',')
```

Comment: Graciass! creo que habia aplicado mal el split, para cosas asi que me recomiendas para evitar el regrex?

Comment: siempre que tienes una cadena y un patron siempre es recomendable regex, en caso de no usarlo vas a tener que jugar mucho con split, te recomiendo esta pagina te ayuda a entender mejor https://regexr.com/ los regex

Comment: No respondas con un Gracias. Si la respuesta resolvió tu pregunta, mejor acepta la respuesta